# Execute a shell command in nodejs that is passed inside a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have setup a nodejs server on a machine where I would like to execute scripts. The command is created on the client side and is sent to the nodejs server through a variable. This command contains a bunch of spaces, along with the script and the arguments needed for it to be executed.

`An example command to be executed on the machine: <script.sh> -input <inputfile>  -output <outputDir> -helper_file <file>`

`var child = exec('$command')`

This command is passed to the server inside a variable. When I try to run the command with the exec process, it stumbles on the spaces and the arguments. How do I get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Any error or something?

Comment: Can you give us some error messages? `exec` command seems doing ok with space and arguments in a string input.

Comment: Try to handle your code with try-catch to know if it's working really or not and try to test the command passed into the variable locally in your system to be sure about syntax

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick responses. I put a try catch to see the error and it seemed that I wasn't passing the argument correctly with the quotes. I have fixed the problem.

A side note, the buffer output returned by the server to the client sucks in formatting. It looks pretty on the sever side.